# On iPhone, how do you allow another app to keep running in the background while your app is running?

Tags: iphone, background-process

For example, if I start a song in Pandora and then open Safari to browse the web the Pandora song will keep playing. However, if I start a song in Pandora and then open my app it kills the Pandora song. How do I let Pandora keep playing while my app is running?

Comment: You write game, isn't it?
What game engine do you use?

Comment: yes. no engine. plain c++ and opengl es 1.1. custom engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the `iOS` system what behavior it should use to integrate the two audio sessions. By default it cancels the background audio when you use audio. But this behavior can be modified as described in the [AVAudioSession docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/WorkingWithOpenALiPodMusicandMovies/WorkingWithOpenALiPodMusicandMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH14-SW1).

To quote:

> **Working with Music Players**
>
> To play audio from a user’s iPod library along with your own sounds
> (as described in iPod Library Access Programming Guide), you must use
> a so-called mixable category configuration for your audio session.
> There are two, alternative ways to configure an audio session as
> mixable:
>
> Use the AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient (or the equivalent
> kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound) category—which is always mixable.
> Use the mixable category override property
> kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, as described in
>
> “Fine-Tuning the Category,” to make an otherwise nonmixable playback
> category mixable. Having used one of these options, your sounds will
> not interrupt a music player—and neither will a music player’s sounds
> interrupt yours.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons why your app might "kill" the background app:

1. It starts to play music of its own
2. You use too much memory for it to keep playing and the OS closes the background app

There is no special option you need to select; you just need to be a "good citizen."

Comment: Hmmm. My app is a game and there is no music - therefore I want people to be able to play music from another app while playing my game. Basically just letting them select their own music. I doubt my game uses too much memory as it is quite small. However my game does have sound effects. Is it not possible since my game app has at least one sound effect?

Comment: From this point of you it doesn't matter whether you play music or "sound effect". You use the audio output port of the device and since your app is in foreground it gets exclusivity for it. So it mutes all other applications in the background. You should remove all audio operations from your app if you don't want this or open it in some kind of shared mode (if it exists, I don't know)

Comment: As I understand it, there are different "channels" for music and sound effect, so make sure you're playing your effects the correct way.